# How to use GPU-acceleration on openCV dnn module on python (Windows)?

Tags: python, gpu, opencv

I want to use `opencv-python4.4` to do inference for YOLOv3. But it uses CPU by default. I have read this instruction [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/), saying the new version `opencv4.2.0` has already supported GPU. But the instruction is only for `Ubuntu` but mine is `Windows10`.

I tried to Could you please walk me through how to pull this off in Wondows10, python? As I directly used it, the error occurred:

```
cv::dnn::dnn4_v20191202::Net::Impl::setUpNet DNN module was not built with CUDA backend; switching to CPU
```

It seems that I have to manually compile `opencv` but isn't it for `Cpp`? But I only want to implement it on `python`. Could anyone give me some instructions?

Answer (score 2):

You will indeed need to build OpenCV yourself.

While you're using the Python bindings for OpenCV, the OpenCV library itself is written in C++ instead of Python. That also explains how OpenCV can use CUDA, another C++ library to access NVidia GPU's.

The instructions you linked are from a person not associated with OpenCV, who admits to an anti-Windows bias. That means those instructions are not useful to you.

[These instructions](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-4-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/) do cover the Windows build.

Summary:

- Use Visual Studio 2019 (Latest C++ compiler from Microsoft) and CMake
- Download & install OpenCV
- Download & install CUDA and cuDNN
- Download & install Anaconda3 and use it as default Python
- Set environment variables so CMake can find your installed libraries
- Set the environment variables and options so CMake knows that you also want the Python bindings for OpenCV
- Use CMake to create .sln file for Visual Studio
- Open .sln in Visual Studio and build it.
- This generates the `cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` file you need.

Comment: I've found the same article myself. But still, thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: I followed the instructions to generate build files. But I couldn't find python binding file anywhere (python3 path has been included)... And specifically I don't understand "Make sure you build release, python bindings cannot by default be generated for a debug configuration". He said building Release, but then swap to Debug somehow... I don't know which one I should do.

Comment: @dexter2406: That comment refers back to the `cmake` command line. It means the arguments to `cmake` should include `--config Release` instead of `--config Debug`.

Comment: So do I still need to modify `pyconfig.h` before build? I just rebuilt it with `set "buildType=Release"` and modified `pyconfig.h`, but there's still no sign of python binding files.

Comment: You'd change `pyconfig.h` only when you're hacking on OpenCV itself and need to debug _that_. I don't think you'd want to do that. But that would only affect what the bindings bind _to_. Did you follow step 4, " Verify that the cmake output detailing the modules to be built includes python3" ?

Comment: No, strangely there's no `python3` in `to be built`. But I input exactly as instructed, i.e. `-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON` and so on. And I didn't see that entry in `CMake` GUI too, even though there's `BUILD_opencv_python_binding_generator` and 'BUILD_opencv_python_tests'...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out... both

```
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF
```

must be specified, otherwise the `to be built` will not include any python module at all.